# Is there an equivalent of Midje facts form in clojure.test?

Tags: clojure, midje, clojure-testing

`(facts ...)` form in Midje, let's us group a bunch of `(fact ..)` forms and also have more `(facts ..)` form under it.

When writing corresponding test suite in clojure.test, what should be used to replace, `(facts ...)` ? Is there something else in clojure with similar semantics ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`testing`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.test/testing) to group your tests. Paraphrased example from the linked doc page:

```
(deftest arithmetic
  (testing "with positive integers"
    (is (= 4 (+ 2 2)))
    (is (= 7 (+ 3 4))))
  (testing "with negative integers"
    (is (= -4 (+ -2 -2)))
    (is (= -1 (+ 3 -4)))))
```

Comment: If what you are looking for is a table of inputs + validated outputs, also look at: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.test/are